# How to use the Shared Preferences to save the calculation data even after the App is killed or destroyed?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using an Activity with implements OnClickListener

Then I have:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Remove title bar */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Themes */
    findViewById(R.id.buttonRED).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonGREEN).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue).setOnClickListener(this);
    /** Hide Auto Keyboard */
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    /** The rest of codes*/
    InputPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePrice);
```

And I have about 15 buttons, 6 TextViews and 1 SeekBar and some animations.

And then i have my onClick with some caculation

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                double price = Double.parseDouble(ePrice.getText()
                        .toString());
                double percent = Double.parseDouble(ePercent.getText()
                        .toString());

                double priceValue = price * percent / 100.0f;
                double percentValue = price - priceValue;

                moneyToGet.setText(String.valueOf(priceValue));
                moneyToPay.setText(String.valueOf(percentValue));

                moneyToGet.setText(String.format("%.02f", priceValue));
                moneyToPay.setText(String.format("%.02f", percentValue));

                // catch
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // write a message to users
                moneyToGet.setText("");
            }
        }
```

**What I want and Why I need the Shared Preferences?**

I want to save the calculation and the animation data of my App in the phone. So that the user can get them even after the App is killed or destroyed.

I read from android developer that the best way of using Shared Preferences is on the onPause not on the onCreate, but I don't know how to use the onPause and where.
I made some researches and I downloaded some samples but they didn't help.

I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is a great way to persist primitive data.

You could use it along the lines of:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){ //save data in onPause

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("price", priceValue);
    editor.putInt("percent", percentValue);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(){ //load data in onPause

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    priceValue = settings.getInt("price",0);
    percentValue = settings.getInt("percent",0);
}
```

Data will be saved in `SharedPreferences` even if app is killed or destroyed. Only time `SharedPreferences` go away is if app is uninstalled or data is cleared.

Comment: Hello, I tried your code also and i get this:priceValue cannot be resolved to a variable!! i tried to do this: private int priceValue;
And when I open my App and do some calulation and then close it and reopen it again there is nothing saved. I also use the uses-permission in manifest!!

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want to save the calculations after the components are clicked, so that's when you should call for the methods, inside the onClick() you're using. 
Using sharedPreferences is very easy, here is some example code:

```
public void saveInternetStatusLight(String color){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();     //constructor of SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); // constructor of editor for writing
        editor.putString("InternetLight", color); //writing a String with "InternetLight" TAG with the value "color"
        editor.commit(); //commit the saved data
    }       
public String loadInternetStatusLight() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(); //constructor sharedpreferences
            return sharedPreferences.getString("InternetLight", "red"); //reading a String with "InternetLigth" TAG with the value, if it's not found it returns the value "red"
        }
```

Also you should use a Switch() in the onClick if you want to separater the cases of the components.

```
Swith(v.getId())
{
case(R.id.buttonRED)
 { 
 }
               //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know about these methods, since they are an important part of the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Second, the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) provides an excellent reference for how to open and close `SharedPreferences` (in `onCreate` and `onStop`). It also shows how, in `onCreate`, these saved values are restored:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

In your example, you will want to add the following at the end of your `onClick` code:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
settings.edit().putInt("price", priceValue).putInt("percent", percentValue).commit();
```

Then replace these lines in the above example:

```
// Restore preferences
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
setSilent(silent);
```

with:

```
// Restore preferences
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int priceValue = settings.getInt("price", 0);
int percentValue = settings.getInt("percent", 0);
moneyToGet.setText(String.format("%.02f", priceValue));
moneyToPay.setText(String.format("%.02f", percentValue));
```

Additionally for your problem, you do not need to override the `onStop` method at all.

Comment: Why its giving me this: moneyToGet cannot be resolved to a variable in onStop and this: priceValue cannot be resolved to a variable in the onClck??

Comment: @user3051834 these are values you reference in your code. It is assumed that these are *class variables*, meaning you should declare them like `private EditText moneyToGet;`